# Como faço para executar o efeito Fade-in no carregamento de uma section

Tags: javascript, html, css

Queria que as divs fossem carregadas apenas quando o usuario chegasse numa determinada section e não no carregamento do body. Assim quando o usuario rola até a section o evento ja aconteceu

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelector('#skills')
            .classList
            .add('loaded');
  });
```

```css
#skills {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
   
    
}
.container__skills {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.skills__card {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
   
}
.skills__card::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    padding: 2.2px; 
    background:linear-gradient(45deg,rgb(255, 0, 149),rgb(0, 110, 255)); 
    -webkit-mask: 
       linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
       linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
            mask-composite: exclude; 
  }
.skills__card img {
    width: 100px;
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(22deg) brightness(105%) contrast(102%);
}
@keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to   { opacity: 1 }
  }
  
  .skills__card {
   
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fade-in 3s normal forwards ease-in-out;
    animation-play-state: paused
  }
  
  #skills.loaded .skills__card {
    animation-play-state: running
  }
  
  #skills.loaded .skills__card:nth-child(2){ animation-delay: 1s }
  #skills.loaded .skills__card:nth-child(3){ animation-delay: 2s }
  #skills.loaded .skills__card:nth-child(4){ animation-delay: 3s }
  #skills.loaded .skills__card:nth-child(5){ animation-delay: 4s }
```

```html
 <section id="skills">
       <div class="container__skills">
            <div class="skills__card">
                <img src="css/images/logo-html5.svg" alt="">
                <h3>HTML</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="skills__card">
                <img src="css/images/logo-css3.svg" alt="">
                <h3>CSS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="skills__card">
                <img src="css/images/logo-javascript.svg" alt="">
                <h3>JAVASCRIPT</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="skills__card">
                <img src="css/images/logo-react.svg" alt="">
                <h3>REACT</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="skills__card">
                <img src="css/images/icon_ux.svg" alt="">
                <h3>UI/UX</h3>
            </div>
       </div>
    </section
```

Answer (score -3):

Sem script so usando o *CSS* funciona assim:

```css
body {
animation: fadein 2s; /* Padrão */
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Webkit */
-moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
-ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* IE */
}
@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0.3; }
to { opacity: 1; } /* Padrão */
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0.3; }
to { opacity: 1; } /* Firefox */
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0.3; 
to { opacity: 1; } /* Webkit */
}
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0.3; }
to { opacity: 1; } /* IE */
}​
```